# Regex to extract two values from single string in Splunk

Tags: regex, splunk-query

I've log statements appearing in Splunk as below.

`info Request method=POST, time=100, id=12345`

`info Response statuscode=200, time=300, id=12345`

I'm trying to write a Splunk query that would extract the time parameter from the lines starting with info Request and info Response and basically find the time difference. Is there a way I can do this in a query? I'm able to extract values separately from each statement but not the two values together.

I'm hoping for something like below, but I guess the piping won't work:

`... | search log="info Request*" | rex field=log "time=(?<time1>[^\,]+)" | search log="info Response*" | rex field=log "time=(?<time2>[^\,]+)" | table time1, time2`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

General process:

1. Extract type into a field
2. Calculate response and request times
3. Group by id
4. Calculate the diff

You may want to use something other than stats(latest) but won't matter if there's only one request/response per id.

```
| rex field=_raw "info (?<type>\w+).*"
| eval requestTime = if(type="Request",time,NULL)
| eval responseTime = if(type="Response",time,NULL)
| stats latest(requestTime) as requestTime latest(responseTime) as responseTime by id
| eval diff = responseTime - requestTime
```